# How would you assign variables to an api call in a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm trying to get input from the user and assign that input to a variable and then post to an API.

```
     @options = {
  :credentials => {
    :account_id => "12345",
    :api_key => "mysecretapikey123456"
  },
  :product => "criminal_database",
  :data => {
  :FirstName => params[:firstName],
  :LastName => params[:lastName],
  :MiddleName => params[:middleName],
  :Address => params[:address],
  :City => params[:city],
  :State => params[:state],
  :Zip => params[:zip],
  :County => params[:county],
  :DOB => params[:DOB],
  :AgeMin => 0,
  :AgeMax => 120,
  :Limit => 1,
  :ExactMatch => "yes"
}
}
  @opt = JSON.generate(@options)
@url = 'https://api.imsasllc.com/v3/'
@response = HTTParty.post(@url, body: @opt, :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
@parsed = JSON.parse(@response.body)
#byebug
p @parsed
```

Above is how I'm attempting to send everything.

Below is the form that I'm using.

```
   <%= form_for(@record_check) do |f| %>
  <% if @record_check.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@record_check.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record_check from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @record_check.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
     <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <%= f.text_field :firstName, :placeholder => "First Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :lastName, :placeholder => "Last Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :middleName, :placeholder => "Middle Name (optional)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :address, :placeholder => "Address (optional)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :city, :placeholder => "City (optional)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :state, :placeholder => "State (optional)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :zip, :placeholder => "Zip Code (optional)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :county, :placeholder => "County (optional)" %>
  <%= f.date_select :DOB, {order: [:month, :day, :year], prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }, start_year: Date.today.year - 18, end_year: Date.today.year - 100}, {required: true} %>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Get Background Check", class: "btn-submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Whenever I submit the form, the API returns an error stating that nothing was posted to it. I'm stumped; I've been working on this for a couple of days... How am I supposed to submit the form input to the method in my controller?

Comment: Can you provide your whole form? Above is not showing the beginning of a form, just the inside fields.

Comment: Thanks, Check the edit

Comment: Post the exact error you get. I think I know the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the primary object in your params:

Your @options variable should use **params[:record_check][:attribute]**  instead of **params[:attribute]**.

So params[:firstName] => params[:record_check][:firstName]

Here is my controller record_checks_controller.rb:

```
class RecordChecksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @record_check = RecordCheck.new
  end

  def create
    @options = {
    :credentials => {
    :account_id => "XXXXXX",
    :api_key => "MCYTAzCBbulF6X2M2H9tP5lOlsWXX"
    },
    :product => "criminal_database",
      :data => {
      :FirstName => params[:record_check][:first_name],
      :LastName => params[:record_check][:last_name],
      :MiddleName => params[:record_check][:middle_name],
      :Address => params[:record_check][:address],
      :City => params[:record_check][:city],
      :State => params[:record_check][:state],
      :Zip => params[:record_check][:zip],
      :County => params[:record_check][:county],
      :DOB => params[:record_check][:dob],
      :AgeMin => 0,
      :AgeMax => 120,
      :Limit => 1,
      :ExactMatch => "yes"
      }
  }
  @opt = JSON.generate(@options)
  @url = 'https://api.imsasllc.com/v3/'
  @response = HTTParty.post(@url, body: @opt, :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
  @parsed = JSON.parse(@response.body)
  #byebug
  p @parsed
  end
end
```

My model record_check.rb

```
class RecordCheck < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And my form new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@record_check) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :middle_name, :placeholder => "Middle Name (optional)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :address, :placeholder => "Address (optional)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :city, :placeholder => "City (optional)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :state, :placeholder => "State (optional)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :zip, :placeholder => "Zip Code (optional)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :county, :placeholder => "County (optional)" %>
  <%= f.date_select :dob, {order: [:month, :day, :year], prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }, start_year: Date.today.year - 18, end_year: Date.today.year - 100}, {required: true} %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Get Background Check", class: "btn-submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My create.html.erb view:

```
<%= @parsed %>
```

My schema for RecordCheck:

```
  create_table "record_checks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "middle_name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.string   "county"
    t.date     "dob"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

Resulting view:

```
{"Results"=>{"Time"=>0.20036697387695, "Message"=>"NO RECORDS FOUND", "TotalRecords"=>0, "Inputs"=>{"Account"=>"128006", "FirstName"=>"John", "LastName"=>"Doe", "AgeMin"=>1, "AgeMax"=>120, "ExactMatch"=>"yes", "Limit"=>1}, "Product"=>"criminal_database", "Records"=>[]}}
```

That's a pretty good API. I don't have any criminal records, thank god.

Comment: I followed everything you did, even created a new rails app to make sure it wasn't something else I had messed up... I am getting this error in both applications ```undefined method `firstName' for #<RecordCheck id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>```

Comment: I had made a mistake with my form, which I revised--had the wrong field names. I also added my schema so you can see my exact database fields, which I suspect is your issue, since your controller does not recognize your method 'firstName'. I suspect that's the issue. Make sure the methods in the form, match the controller. You'll notice I'm not saving anything to the database for RecordSet, just instantiating the @record_set object.

Comment: Wow thank you so much @carson you've helped me tremendously. Currently a junior dev working solo and I cannot tell you enough how much I appreciate your help.

Comment: Its always something simple. Good luck @steviepinero!